# Find longest sequence of characters in stack

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, loops, stack

Hi I was solving a problem:

> Given a base-10 integer, n, convert it to binary (base-2). Then find and
>   print the base-10 integer denoting the maximum number of consecutive 1's
>   in n's binary representation. For e.g. for n=5, base-2 = 101 so the output should be 1, for n = 439, base-2 = 110110111 so the output should be 3.

Below is my code solution for the same:

```
class Solution {

    static int CalcBinary (int n) {
        Stack<int> binRep = new Stack<int>();
        while (n > 0) {
            int i = n%2;
            binRep.Push (i);
            n = n/2;
        }
        int oldCount = 0, newCount = 0;
        while (binRep.Count > 0){
            int val = binRep.Pop();
            if (val == 1) {
                newCount++;
            } else {
                if (newCount > oldCount) {
                    oldCount = newCount;
                }
                newCount = 0;
            }
        }
        return (newCount > oldCount) ? newCount : oldCount;
    }

    static void Main(String[] args) {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine (CalcBinary(n));
    }
}
```

The code runs fine and passes all the test cases like for n = 5, 6, 439, etc. Only question I have is that if there is any optimized solution to do the same. Someone else has posted the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512283/finding-longest-sequence-of-a-particular-value), but all the replies to that question seem to be same with O(n) time complexity. Another thing is I can use array instead of Stack, but would it make any difference??

Comment: What would be the answer for 437 (`110110101`)? 2?

Comment: I think counting 1-bits in a number (which is O(number of 1)) may be applied to this case to get better than O(number of bits) for fixed length numbers... (just a guess, not completely sure if it will work out)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean `O(log n)` unless `n` is the number of binary digits rather than the number itself.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use a Stack or array - you can work directly on the integer value? _while (n > 0) { if ((n%2) == 1) ......._

Comment: @UweKeim, I have had issues before that my question though valid on stackoverflow, got negative on code review. So I prefer to ask them here.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, yes the answer should be 2 for 437.

Comment: @apokryfos, yes my mistake, the n in the time complexity O(n) refers to the number of binary digits and not the int argument passed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public int CalcBinary(int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i + result < 32 && (n >> i) != 0; i++)
    {
        if (((n >> i) & 1) == 1)
            current += 1;
        else
        {
            if (current > result) 
                result = current;
            current = 0;
        }
    }

    return result == 0 ? current : result;
}
```

I'm not so good at big O arithmetic, but I think this solution should be faster since I don't use any other classes but simple bit shifting.

And I **stop early** if there is no longer solution possible (`i + result < 32`).

**Note** that this is only for **32bit** integers. For 64bit adjust the mentioned condition. And it works only for **positive** values (a set sign bit can produce wrong results for example for `111....111101`).

---

Update: added the `(n >> i) != 0` condition as suggested by @Scott-Chamberlain (it checks if there are still `1`s to come at all).

Comment: You also could bail out earlier with `i + result < 32 && n >> i != 0`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I don't get my head around it, shouldn't that be `i + result < 32 || (n >> i) == 0`? So the "upper rest" of the int is zeros?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ah sorry, my bad, `for` loop's condition to continue... I turned it around in my head to an exit condition

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you calculate `maximum_consecutive` while converting binary instead of waiting convert done, then calculate `maximum_consecutive` again from the stack ?

I think you should change to this.

```
class Solution {

static int CalcBinary (int n) {
    int oldCount = 0, newCount = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        int i = n%2;
        n = n/2;

        if (i == 1) {
            newCount++;
        }
        else {
            if (newCount > oldCount) {
                oldCount = newCount;
            }
            newCount = 0;
        }

    }
    return (newCount > oldCount) ? newCount : oldCount;
}

static void Main(String[] args) {
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine (CalcBinary(n));
}
}
```

Comment: yes actually this saves me from creating a Stack. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For bit-fiddling fun and minimal branching:

```
int[] lookup = new[]
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};
int LongestRunOfBits(uint value)
{
    int max = 0;
    while(1 << max < value + 1)
    {
        uint testValue = ~value;
        uint lookupIndex = ((uint)((testValue & -testValue) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27;
        int trailingZeros = lookup[lookupIndex];
        max = trailingZeros - ((trailingZeros - max) & ((trailingZeros - max) >> 31));
        value >>= 1;
    }
    return max;
}
```

This combines the following operations:

[Compute the maximum of two integers without branching](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax) (QuAD version)

[Count the consecutive zero bits (trailing) on the right with multiply and lookup](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightMultLookup) (if it counts trailing zero bits on `value`, then it counts trailing one bits on `~value`)

Let's follow this through for `value` 6, or `110`:

Now we have:

```
             value : 00000000000000000000000000000110
            ~value : 11111111111111111111111111111001
trailing zero bits : 0
   value after rsh : 00000000000000000000000000000011
            ~value : 11111111111111111111111111111100
trailing zero bits : 2
   value after rsh : 00000000000000000000000000000001 //skip this last iteration
            ~value : 11111111111111111111111111111110 //as it will now be impossible
trailing zero bits : 1                                //to find a value > 2
```

by finding the maximum number of trailing zero bits of `~value` we are effectively finding the maximum number of trailing one bits for `value`. If we carry on right shifting until there are no more bits left, the longest run of set bits is the maximum value of the trailing zero bits operation we performed over `~value`. Hooray. Once we've found the value 2 and there are 2 or less bits remaining in the value, we can bail early as we can be sure no larger value than 2 can be found, so the last iteration can be skipped.